# Is it Possible to Exchange Turkish Lira Coins in Tbilisi?

Tags: turkey, exchange, georgia-country

Does anyone know if I can exchange Lira **coins** in Tbilisi?

I'm usually careful to not return home with coins since nobody will take them on exchange, but ended up with a bunch of Lira. I would be glad to part with them on our upcoming trip to Tbilisi if it's possible.

Comment: I'm going to Tbilisi next week, so will be able to check it there.  I'll try to get some info from my contacts there in the mean time.

Comment: @AleksG Did you find out by any chance?

Comment: sorry, didn't get to a computer straight away - posting an answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in Tbilisi for the past few days, so could check it here.  I asked around in a few currency exchange places - and none of them accept foreign coins, lira or otherwise.  One of the places suggested that TBC bank branches may be able to exchange coins, however I didn't manage to get to a bank.

My advice would be to take the lira coins with you and head straight for a bank branch.  While the exchange rate isn't as favourable as in independent exchange centres, at least you may stand a better chance.

Comment: Looks like I'll be going to Turkey after Ramadan, so might as well wait. Thanks for replying and hope this reminds people to spend their coins before leaving.